# Changing gvim double-click behavior

Tags: gvim

When I double click in gvim it causes the current word to be selected.  However, by default, a 'word' excludes special characters.  I would like, for example, to be able to double click on a UNIX or Windows path and have that whole path highlighted.  Can I change what gvim considers to be a word?

By way of analogy, xterm takes a -cc, 'character class range' switch.   Any contiguous characters in a given class are highlighted if I double-click on one of them.  I can define a character class which includes alphanumerics and the forward-slash, so when I click on a UNIX path, it highlights that whole path.  I'd like something similar in gvim.

Comment: If you're double clicking in vim you're doing it wrong :)

Comment: ^^ why? It's not vi anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `:help double-click`:

> A double click on a word selects that word.  'iskeyword' is used to
>   specify which characters are included in a word.

So you need to change `iskeyword` to include slashes. `set iskeyword+=/` worked for me. Keep in mind this also affects other stuff, e.g. searching. See `:h iskeyword`.

Comment: Thanks!  That seems to work for me.  I guess I'll find the side-effects in due course.